# Why does my list not change with lambda?

Tags: java, lambda

I have the following simple method:

```
public void exercise2(List<String> list) {
    list.stream().filter(s -> s.length() % 2 == 0).collect(Collectors.toList());
  }
```

And simple test, which does not complete successfully:

```
@Test
  public void testExercise2() {
    Lesson1 lesson1 = new Lesson1();
    List<String> list = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList("alpha", "bravo", "charlie", 
                                                      "delta", "echo", "foxtrot"));
    List<String> inputList = new ArrayList<>(list);
    lesson1.exercise2(list);
    assertEquals("Input " + inputList.toString(), Arrays.asList("echo"), list);
  }
```

Comment: Streams never modify the original list.

Comment: Just do this `list = list.stream().filter(s -> s.length() % 2 == 0).collect(Collectors.toList());`

Comment: Please include the exact error/failure you are getting. This will help people determine the cause, and possible solution.

Comment: @SLaks But how i can change the list when return type is void?

Comment: If you want to modify the list, try `removeIf()`.

Comment: @shmosel I try to use it. There is still not working/

Comment: Sorry to hear that...

Answer (score 3):

Streams never modify the original list.

Your function creates a new list, then ignores it.

Comment: In the [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html) of the Collectors you can find an example for using `collect`. Here is the relevant part `List<String> list = people.stream().map(Person::getName).collect(Collectors.toList());`

Comment: I don't understand, how i can change input arraylist:(

Comment: @Stefan but that still wouldn't modify the list: it merely assigns a new value to the variable, which is discarded once the method returns.

Comment: @AndyTurner Do you know how i can solve this issue?

Comment: @AndyTurner My mistake, sorry. Andy, you are right.

Comment: @cori: Streams can't do that.